# Code Injection in Linux -- shellcode not working for some reason

Tags: c, linux, shellcode

I am trying the examples of code injection in the following link:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/6210/print

Everything is working well(I mean it will inject a string to target process using the shellcode in that example), but when I tried to inject my shellcode, the program does not work at all.

Here is how I get the shellcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  printf("Hello");
  return 0;
}
```

Then, I compile the source code and use gdb to disassemble the code.

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080483e4 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483e5 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483e7 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x080483ea <+6>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x080483ed <+9>: mov    $0x80484e0,%eax
   0x080483f2 <+14>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x080483f5 <+17>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x080483fa <+22>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x080483ff <+27>:    leave  
   0x08048400 <+28>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/30bx main
0x80483e4 <main>:   0x55    0x89    0xe5    0x83    0xe4    0xf0    0x83    0xec
0x80483ec <main+8>: 0x10    0xb8    0xe0    0x84    0x04    0x08    0x89    0x04
0x80483f4 <main+16>:    0x24    0xe8    0x06    0xff    0xff    0xff    0xb8    0x00
0x80483fc <main+24>:    0x00    0x00    0x00    0xc9    0xc3    0x90
```

Then, I just copy those 30 bytes as my shellcode and use it, but it does not work. Does anyone know why it does not work? How to fix it? Thanks.

PS: By the way, I wonder how to fix from the source code, not simply writing assembly code.

Comment: I guess the injected program's `printf` is not at `main - 0xe4` (0x8048300).

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide us with the error message

Comment: You are also trying to use an exploit that was known in 2002 and has been repeatedly closed by kernel updates after each CVE was reported. (eg. [latest ptrace exploit closed](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=e268337dfe26dfc7efd422a804dbb27977a3cccc) ) Check to make sure you can use the exploit on your kernel version or you may just be beating you head into a brick wall.

Comment: Did you also read the **note** 'the instruction set you are using is specific to intel's architecture, amd's architecture may differ and these instruction set will not run on amd. check out amd's manual for its instruction set'

Comment: I tried the shellcode in the example. It is working and able to inject "hello world" to target process. But when I tried to use other shellcode. I cannot see any difference. (Cannot see the injected string).